# Best Hibernate primary key Generation Type when using multiple databases and Liquidbase

Tags: database, spring-boot, jpa, liquibase

I have an application using Hibernate for persistence and I'm using Liquibase to handle model version migrations.

My application needs to support a variety of databases (Oracle, DB2, MS Sql, MySql, and not a must, but H2 as well). Is there a best practice for handling the primary key generation type in this case where I need to support multiple databases?

I came across [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/5-things-you-need-to-know-when-using-hibernate-with-mysql/) which suggests:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
@GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
```

Is this the correct way, or are there any other best practices for Hibernate/Liquidbase in general with multiple db implementations?

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [this document](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/community/add-primary-key.html), that explains how you can add a primary key using liquibase.